# Use of particle を with 取り組み and 期待する

Tags: grammar, particle-を

> ▽アジアの中心が中国にシフトしつつある中、日本が世界で戦える人財づくり**を**企業・学校・政府と本格的に取り組む仕組みづくり**に**期待したい（自動車）([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/business_tokushu/2018_1029.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_001))

1) I don't understand what the を is doing there? 取り組む doesn't take the を particle normally...?

2)Is 仕組みづくり the object of the verb 期待する(the thing 'hoped')? if yes, why isn't the particle を used instead as in the following sentence?

> 彼の成功を期待している We expect him to succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It's the object of 取り組む. It is true that 取り組み doesn't normally take を, but I think it's the only way to interpret this sentence. FYI, BCCWJ has four examples of を取り組む and 1175 examples of に取り組む.

2) Yes 仕組みづくり is what the person is hoping for, although it's not a direct object, strictly speaking. ～を期待する and ～に期待する are interchangeable.

I feel this sentence is still awkward. This person says "企業・学校・政府と", but what is the subject of 取り組む, then?

I think the sentence would be cleaner if we rephrased it like this:

> 《日本が世界で戦える人財づくり**に**企業**と**学校**と**政府**が**本格的に取り組**める(ような)**》仕組みづくりに期待したい
>   I hope for a new framework which allows companies, schools and the government to work through the development of world-class human resources.